# JPA persistence.xml data-source for SE app

Tags: java, jpa

Various sources (e.g. [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cfgdepds005.htm#TopLinkJDBC)) say that you have to specify jdbc connection details in your persistence.xml for Java SE apps which use JPA via things like `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="..."/>`.

This is a real pain when you want to run the app against different databases, for example local, test and production. I currently get around this by having multiple persistence-units that are all effectively the same but with different connection details, and then get the app to pick the right persistence-unit based on the environment that it is running in.

The problems with this are:

- Duplication of config. When I add an Entity class I have to add `<class>MyClass</class>` to every persistence-unit. I would rather just specify it once.
- Database connection config packaged with the app. If I want to change what database is being used in an environment, I need to fiddle with persistence.xml and re-build the app. I would rather have a config file in each of my environments which specifies the database credentials. That way, I could have many environments but just a single persistence-unit defined, and I could change the database credentials for a given environment by just editing one file in that environment and then re-starting the app.

Do you know of a better way to configure persistence? Is there some way of getting `<jta-data-source>` or `<non-jta-data-source>` to do something appropriate in a Java SE environment?

Answer (score 1):

U can config it manually in code

```
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "YourURL");
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UnitName", props);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: Thanks. That way I could manage the connection details however I like, e.g. store them in a file on each server, read them in, initialise the EMFs. I'll try that and see how it goes.